# how to retreive a photo user from the user.list api of the google admin SDK?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have trouble understanding the problem to recover the user photo from google.

First, the photo user is authorized for everyone. Normally it is saved in Account google(people), see screenshot, below.[image]

In my test procedure, there is no account id in the account google  (people).

so, I take another solution: user.list at admin google.
I found the photo url: user.thumbnailPhotoUrl.
it doesn't display because "private" is in that URL. yet in the google account, the photo is public.

so How to get the real url?

```js
function doGet() {

var emailadresse = 'testbertrand@radiopresence.com';
var id_user = '117966962362496071521';

var parm_table = UserPhotoTest (id_user);
Logger.log('parm_table  :'+parm_table );

}


function UserPhotoTest (user_id) {
var accountId =user_id;
Logger.log ('function userphoto  - N°account id  :'+accountId );

  var val_photoUrl = "";
  var val_namefile = "";

try 
{ var person = People.People.get('people/' + accountId, {personFields: 'names,photos,phoneNumbers,addresses,birthdays,sipAddresses,organizations,genders'});
  //** var val_displayName_P = person.names[0].displayName;
   var val_photoUrl = person.photos[0].url.replace("=s100","=s128");
   var val_namefile = get_namefile(val_photoUrl);
  }
  catch (err)
  {
  Logger.log ('function userphoto  - Error : '+err);
  
 var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(emailadresse); 
 
 var val_photoUrl = user.thumbnailPhotoUrl
    if (val_photoUrl.indexOf("private") > -1)
    {
    var testphotoadmin  = AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get(emailadresse);
    // in document, I didn't understand it for AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.get(emailadresse);
    // May you help me to developp here
    //   how to retreive a real url ?  
    // val_photoUrl = ...
    }
  

  
  }
  
  var parm_photo = val_photoUrl;
return parm_photo;
}
```

Comment: Could you share more details about what is your exact goal? Seems like you are using the Admin SDK and the People API however if you just want the profile picture People API should be enough.

Comment: yes, Normally, I took only people api but it doesn't work because it did not found  the photo user in people api , yet it exists well at an acount google !... and more, this photo is for the public and no private , see screenshot above . 
Then how to do ot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have noticed is that photos uploaded from the Admin console as an Admin if you have a Google Workspace account they remain as `private` when retrieving the `thumbnailPhotoUrl`. This function should allow you to check whether the URL is private or not:

```
function retrievePhoto(){
  var user = 'youremail@yourdomain.com';
  var photo = AdminDirectory.Users.get(user,{fields:'thumbnailPhotoUrl'});
  console.log(photo);
}
```

Using the above code should retrieve your `thumbnailPhotoUrl` when using the `Admin SDK` in App Script. If the profile picture was updated from the Admin console most likely the URL will show as `private`. If the thumbnailUrl still shows as private try allowing this [setting](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7326921) in the Workspace console and update the profile picture in [aboutme.google.com](http://aboutme.google.com/) as this should set the picture as public.